# How to segue from More tabBarController to child viewController?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tab bar app with 6 tab bar items [News, Chats, Services, Notifications, Profile, Events]
Automatically, the last item will be transformed in a `More` item.
Now, Profile and Events will show in a tableViewController when More is tapped.

Events has 5 childViewControllers.

My questions is: how can I segue from Events to any of its children? 
Every time, I try to segue, it outputs error `reason: 'Receiver (<UIMoreNavigationController: 0x7fb0f1814e00>) has no segue with identifier 'fromEventsVcToEventsComposer''`  The identifier is correct.

What have I tried?

```
self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromEventsVcToEventsComposer", sender: nil)

self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromEventsVcToEventsComposer", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if let events = self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.viewControllers?.last as? EventsVC { 
  events.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromEventsVcToEventsComposer", sender: nil)  
}
```

Comment: Long story short, it should have been `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromEventsVcToEventsComposer", sender: nil)`